# Media queries for dynamically added images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added some images dynamically on my page using js code like this:

```
if (doorcount == 1) {
$("#doorframe").html('<img src="content/image/door2unopenedlight.jpg" />');
$("#map1").html('<img src="content/image/map2light.jpg" />')
}
else if (doorcount == 2) {
$("#doorframe").html('<img src="content/image/door3unopenedlight.jpg" />');
$("#map1").html('<img src="content/image/map3light.jpg" />')
}
```

and so on.

The #doorframe and #map1 divs have fixed sizes which match the sizes of the jpeg images I have right now and it all looks fine on a desktop/laptop sized screen. However, I want to use media queries for rendering the same page on smaller screens. I know how to do the same for everything else on the page but how do I go about altering the size of these dynamically added images to scale according to the screen size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell the images to scale to the width of the containing element. E.g.

```
img {width: 100%;}
```

Just wrap that in a media query so that it only applies where you want it to.

Comment: Didn't think it'd be this simple :P. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add This to Your Style Sheet

```
img{max-width:100%;}
```